# Change of support or inverse problem where block data is not the arithmetic mean

Tags: spatial, harmonic-mean

The *change of support problem* or *inverse problem* in geostatistics is concerned with inferences about the values of variables at points or block different from those at which it has been observed. There are a number of papers on the subject:

- [Wang et al. (2016)](http://A%20geostatistical%20approach%20to%20the%20change-of-support%20problem%20and%20variable-support%20data%20fusion%20in%20spatial%20analysis)
- [Gelfand et al. (2001)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10109-015-0224-4)
- [Gotway and Young (2002)](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/~drf/misc/airs/maup_summary.pdf)

However all of them seem to assume that the block average is the arithmetic average. I.e.:

$$Z(B_i) = \frac{1}{|B_i|} \int_{B_i} Z(s)ds$$

Where $Z(B_i)$ is the block process, $B_i$ is the spatial support of $Z(B_i)$ and $Z(s)$ is a process associated with spatial points $s_i$ rather than blocks.

Are there papers that consider cases where the block average is not so simple (e.g. harmonic mean rather than arithmetic mean)?

Comment: This doesn't fall under the usual geostatistical theory because (unlike the arithmetic mean) these functionals are *nonlinear*.  They are typically addressed by modeling a transformation of the variable; for instance, the harmonic mean is directly obtained from a block average of the reciprocal of the field values.  You might want to direct your attention therefore to literature on "nonlinear geostatistics" and some of its methods, including stochastic simulation of random fields.